# IOS 11 Set color for BarButtonItems in enable state

Tags: swift, colors, ios11, uibarbuttonitem

I have a question in IOS 11 . Color of BarButtonItems in navigation bar changed when they have been enabled and disabled. I want to find why their color changed. I want to set their color With this code

```
UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self]).tintColor = UIColor.red
```

but this code set color for barbuttonitem is enable state and disable mode.I think some features for barbuttonitems changed in IOS11. Can you help me to set color for BarButtonItems just for enable state.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't set state-specific appearance options for `UIButton`.

Comment: @Samah i want to set specific color for barbuttonitem in disalbed mode. can you help me for solving this problem?